# How to get started with CodeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks

So I have a question about how to get started with CodeBlocks IDE: 
I am given a Folder with c-files. It is stored on my Desktop. I want to open it in CodeBlocks as a new Workspace. But how do I do that?

Also, when I try to create a new Project (create a new Project -> console application -> Project Name = hello_world, Project Folder = class\ ) for some reason it says the Project couldn't be created.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a full path for the project folder

Click the browse button on the right of the folder edit and browse to where you want to add it, the add the '\class' after closing the directory browser